# Operands could not broadcast together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a model using mini batches but I'm having a .... error.

I'm using the same function I've already used (and it worked) with other models, but this time is crashing.

```
def random_mini_batches(X, Y, mini_batch_size = 64):
"""
Creates a list of random minibatches from (X, Y)

Arguments:
X -- input data, of shape (input size, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector (1, number of examples)
mini_batch_size - size of the mini-batches, integer

Returns:
mini_batches -- list of synchronous (mini_batch_X, mini_batch_Y)
"""

m = X.shape[1]                  # number of training examples
mini_batches = []

# Step 1: Shuffle (X, Y)
permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
shuffled_X = X.iloc[:, permutation]
shuffled_Y = Y[:, permutation].reshape((Y.shape[0],m))

# Step 2: Partition (shuffled_X, shuffled_Y). Minus the end case.
num_complete_minibatches = math.floor(m/mini_batch_size) # number of mini batches of size mini_batch_size in your partitionning
for k in range(0, num_complete_minibatches):
    mini_batch_X = shuffled_X.iloc[:, k * mini_batch_size : k * mini_batch_size + mini_batch_size]
    mini_batch_Y = shuffled_Y[:, k * mini_batch_size : k * mini_batch_size + mini_batch_size]
    mini_batch = (mini_batch_X, mini_batch_Y)
    mini_batches.append(mini_batch)

# Handling the end case (last mini-batch < mini_batch_size)
if m % mini_batch_size != 0:
    mini_batch_X = shuffled_X.iloc[:, num_complete_minibatches * mini_batch_size : m]
    mini_batch_Y = shuffled_Y[:, num_complete_minibatches * mini_batch_size : m]
    mini_batch = (mini_batch_X, mini_batch_Y)
    mini_batches.append(mini_batch)

return mini_batches
```

I've used this function in a NN with 20 layers and this X and Y: [image: X and Y shapes]
And now I'm trying use it again with a 5 layer NN and shapes [image: X and Y shapes of the new case]

However, I'm getting this error [image: Error] at this part of the code `epoch_cost += minibatch_cost/num_minibatches`.

The full code would be this:

```
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        epoch_cost = 0
        num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size) # number of minibatches of size minibatch_size in the train set

        minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size)

        for minibatch in minibatches:

            #Select a minibatch
            (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch

            _, minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y})

            epoch_cost += minibatch_cost/num_minibatches

    # Print the cost every epoch
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_cost))
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
            costs.append(epoch_cost)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using:

```
epoch_cost += np.mean(minibatch_cost)/num_minibatches
```

If anyone have another solution I would love to hear it.